# What are the negative-dimentional n-sphere and n-cube?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

The generalized formula for the volume and surface area of n-sphere allows to evaluate volumes and areas of negative-dimentional n-spheres.

$$\begin{array}{ll}
S_{n-1}(R) &= \displaystyle{\frac{n\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}R^{n-1}} \\[1 em]
V_n(R) &= \displaystyle{\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + 1)}}R^n
\end{array}$$

I wonder what the negative-dimentional n-spheres are? Are they like pseudosphere or hyperboloid?

In general, what a negative-dimentional vector space is?

Comment: Why stop at integers? You can take any real number.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus what non-integer positive dimentional space and n-sphere is clear: a fractal. But what about negative?

Comment: A fractal sphere sounds like a contradiction in terms. So I can't picture that any more than I can picture a sphere in a negative-dimensional setting.

Comment: @MvG if distance is defined on a fractal (for instance, on Serpinsky triangle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension#mediaviewer/File:Sierpinski_deep.svg ), then all points equally distant from a given one form a sphere.

Comment: In topology it sometimes makes sense to think of the empty space as the $(-1)$-sphere.

Comment: @Anixx: If $S$ is a sphere in a space $X$ of fractal dimension $d$, do you have any reason to believe: 1. The dimension of $S$ is independent of (a) the fractal $X$ (i.e., is a function of $d$ alone)? (b) the radius $R$? 2. The fractal dimension of $S$ is $d - 1$? 3. The volume of $S$ is given by the formula in your post? Unless all these preliminary questions have affirmative answers, it seems to me the question is on shaky ground. (_Then_ we can haggle about what "negative-dimensional" might mean.)

Comment: @Eric Wofsey but does it obey the above formulas?

Comment: I cannot evaluate these physics papers, but apparently there are some viewpoints where negative dimensions help: Roger Penrose: "Applications of Negative Dimensional Tensors." G. Parisi and N. Sourlas, "Random Magnetic Fields, Supersymmetry, and Negative Dimensions," *Phys. Rev. Lett.* 43 (1979) 744.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way of making sense of all integer dimensions, although I'm not sure if it will be useful to you.
Let us start with the collection of Euclidean spaces,
$$
E=\{\mathbb R^n;n\in\mathbb Z,n\geq0\},
$$
for example.
There two operations for spaces in $E$, the direct sum and the tensor product.
If we identify spaces of the same dimension, we have $\mathbb R^n\oplus\mathbb R^m=\mathbb R^{n+m}$ and $\mathbb R^n\otimes\mathbb R^m=\mathbb R^{nm}$.
These operations are associative, commutative and distributive.

These operations don't make $(E,\oplus,\otimes)$ into a ring, but that can be remedied.
One way is to formally let $n$ range over all of $\mathbb Z$ and define things the same way.
If we call this new collection of spaces $F$, then $(F,\oplus,\otimes)$ is (in an obvious way) ring-isomoprhic to $(\mathbb Z,+,\times)$.
Then objects like $\mathbb R^{-7}\in F$ don't have any other meaning than being in some kind of an extension of the set of Euclidean spaces.
I don't see any obvious way of doing geometry in an object of $F$, especially in a way that would include those volume formulas.

In this case the construction leads to a relatively trivial object (the ring of integers), but it at least gives some way of attaching a meaning to negative dimensional spaces.
That is, $\mathbb R^{-4}$ is the thing (not a vector space!) that satisfies $\mathbb R^{-4}\oplus\mathbb R^4=0$ (something like the direct sum of vector spaces), where $0=\mathbb R^0$ is the zero space.
Negative dimension cancels positive dimension, whatever that means.

(This answer was inspired by the concept of [representation ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_ring), a way of forming a ring out of vector spaces in way that is useful in representation theory.)

Sidenote: $1/\Gamma(1+n/2)=0$ for $n\in\{-2,-6,-10,-14,\dots\}$.
This would be really weird behaviour for something that resembles the geometrical idea of volume.

Comment: Curiosity: that sequence is just the negative number of electrons for subshells is quantum mechanics! Weird coincidence if provided a reason for that...

Comment: Extending the monoid $E$ to a group, and more generally, the monoid of finite dimensional vector bundles over a space, is the basic construction in K-theory